# Could someone give some tips or check simple class diagram for mobile application?

Tags: uml, modeling, mobile-application, class-diagram

[image]

I'm working on preparing a class diagram for mobile application. The application is meant to be something like a diary from journeys. Here are the requirements:

1. One user can create many trips.
2. One trip can be to one or more places (destinations, cities).
3. There might be assigned many albums with pictures to each trip, categorised in custom way, for example one album is for food pictures, one is for people user met during a trip etc.
4. Each picture can (but doesn't have to) have a description.
5. User can add contacts to a contact book.

I have created a very simple UML class diagram using StarUML. I am not sure if it all is correct, maybe there should be some association class used instead of something or maybe different kinds of relationships.

Could someone please check it and maybe give some tips and corrections?

Answer (score 1):

- `id` is nothing you would like to have in an object. It has it's integral ID already given by the run time system. Remove it (unless you have good reasons for it, like being a passport id or so)
- `Category` appears twice. Not a good idea. Choose unique names.
- Your `Contact` appears to be way too simplistic.
- `Delete()` in `Trip` does not seem to make sense since you'd apply that to a collection which `Trip` is not.
- Naming associations is not that helpful. Rather assign role names to either end.

Comment: Please note that SO is no place for code/design review. You will pass this time for being a newbie. Next time ask a specific question.